# How do I fix hover property of a div?

Tags: css, html, hover

One would tink that changing :hover of a parent element applies the transformation to each of the child elements. However,

```
<a href="" class="pressRelease"><div class="pressRelease">
    <div class="timestamp">
        <p class="timestamp">02 Feb 2012</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pressReleaseTitle">
        <p class="pressReleasetitle">release title</p>
    </div>
</div></a>

div.pressRelease :hover {
    background-color:#F2F2F2
}

div.timestamp {
    float:left;
    width: 110px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:21px;
}

div.pressReleaseTitle {
    float:right;
    width:498px;
    padding-top:23px;
    padding-bottom:21px;
    padding-left:25px;
}

a.pressRelease {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#767676;
    display:block;
    background-color:#063
}
```

I have this code in the HTML and CSS files, and the behavior is pretty odd: when I hover over the timestamp, only timespamp background color is changed, while the color of press release title remains unchanged. Obviously, I want the whole press release to be highlighted

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to remove the space between `:hover` and your css element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving `float:left` to parent div as it is not wrapping child elements with 'float'

in addition to the error fix mentioned by Praveen

```
div.pressRelease {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Error:

Replace:

```
div.pressRelease :hover
```

With:

```
div.pressRelease:hover
```

There should not be any space before `:hover`.

#### Suggestions:

1. The way you have written your HTML is not valid. An inline element `<a>` cannot contain a block element `<div>`.
2. The browsers will ignore the surrounding `<a>` tag. So, if you give a code like:

   ```
    <a><div><p></p></div></a>
   ```

   It will be rendered as

   ```
    <a></a><div><p></p></div>
   ```

Comment: If the page uses an HTML5 doctype, then wrapping block elements within `a` tags is allowed, more info on this subject:
http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

Comment: Hover properties are still applied, but separately to each child within parent div. I've removed the space, behavior remains unchanged. Also, thank you for highlithing the errors and putting your suggestions :)

Comment: use `float:left` for `div.pressRelease` as it is not wrapping child elements

Comment: Okay, remove the `<a href..>` and `</a>` and try again?

Comment: @Uttara don't want to steal rep, so could you please post your comment as a separate answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `oveflow:auto` to `a` tag to wrap the inner elements.

And remove div from `div.pressRelease:hover`

```
.pressRelease:hover {
    background-color:#F2F2F2
}

div.timestamp {
    float:left;
    width: 110px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:21px;
}

div.pressReleaseTitle {
    float:right;
    width:498px;
    padding-top:23px;
    padding-bottom:21px;
    padding-left:25px;
}

a.pressRelease {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#767676;
    display:block;
    background-color:#063; overflow:auto
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nKA7U/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, but the solution was adding `code`float:left to the parent div so it would actually wrap child elements :)